# RFID link budget formula

Tags: rfid

I am attempting to design an RFID system. But before I do I need to simulate this system. I know I need to use the link budget equation to see whether or not the RFID tag will receive enough power to activate it and then backscatter the signal to the UHF RFID reader. Unfortunately, there are alot of equations online. How do I choose which one to use? I want to be able to predict the power to within 10-5%.

An example from the equation below there are a few derivations from this equation, in addition, they also use the Friis equation. Which one is more suitable for an RFID system.

[image]